How to compare two rows column by column?
I have two interfaces that parse the data and put the converted data into the table called rbc_swift_parser.
One interface (old) is written in C and the other in Java. Java one is still in a test environment. I have one primary key called host_reference. A single deal will have two rows in the table one is parsed by the Java interface and the other is parsed by the C interface. Can I compare each column (the total columns are 103) for a single deal? In short, my query will show which columns do not match each other. I tried using partition but it is not working.
Query:
select * from rbc_swift_parser where deal_number = '11NOV2400000018'
The above query will show two rows. I have read-only access to DB.
Query I am using:
SELECT 
    a.host_reference,
    a.deal_number,
    CASE WHEN a.column1 <> b.column1 THEN 'Mismatch' ELSE 'Match' END AS column1_comparison,
    CASE WHEN a.column2 <> b.column2 THEN 'Mismatch' ELSE 'Match' END AS column2_comparison,
    -- Repeat for all 103 columns
    CASE WHEN a.column103 <> b.column103 THEN 'Mismatch' ELSE 'Match' END AS column103_comparison
FROM 
    rbc_swift_parser a
JOIN 
    rbc_swift_parser b
ON 
    a.deal_number = b.deal_number
    AND a.host_reference <> b.host_reference
WHERE 
    a.deal_number = '11NOV2400000018';


This seems to be about a query, so please remove all references to Java, C etc, and show schema, sample data and expected output

"I tried using partition but it is not working", and then you do show a query without the term partition ?  BTW: I think you should use FULL OUTER JOIN

Not quite sure what you want to do - your query should give you missmatches. It's just to much code to write for all those columns.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table rbc_swift_parser ( host_reference   Number(6) Primary Key,
                                deal_number      Number(6),
                                column1          Varchar2(32),
                                column2          Varchar2(32),
                                column3          Varchar2(32),
                                --
                                column103        Varchar2(32)    );
Insert Into rbc_swift_parser
Select 1, 101, 'col_1 A', 'col_2 B', 'col_3 C', 'col_103 Z' From Dual Union All 
Select 2, 101, 'col_1 A', 'col_2 X', 'col_3 C', 'col_103 Z' From Dual Union All 
--
Select 3, 222, 'col_1 Y', 'col_2 B', 'col_3 C', 'col_103 Z' From Dual Union All 
Select 4, 222, 'col_1 A', 'col_2 B', 'col_3 C', 'col_103 Z' From Dual Union All 
--
Select 5, 303, 'col_1 A', 'col_2 B', 'col_3 C', 'col_103 Z' From Dual Union All 
Select 6, 303, 'col_1 A', 'col_2 B', 'col_3 C', 'col_103 Z' From Dual;

--      Y o u r    S Q L    c o d e :
SELECT 
    a.host_reference,
    a.deal_number,
    CASE WHEN a.column1 <> b.column1 THEN 'Mismatch' ELSE 'Match' END AS column1_comparison,
    CASE WHEN a.column2 <> b.column2 THEN 'Mismatch' ELSE 'Match' END AS column2_comparison,
    -- Repeat for all 103 columns
    CASE WHEN a.column103 <> b.column103 THEN 'Mismatch' ELSE 'Match' END AS column103_comparison
FROM 
    rbc_swift_parser a
JOIN 
    rbc_swift_parser b
ON 
    a.deal_number = b.deal_number
    AND a.host_reference <> b.host_reference
WHERE 
    a.deal_number = '101';
    
HOST_REFERENCE DEAL_NUMBER COLUMN1_ COLUMN2_ COLUMN103
-------------- ----------- -------- -------- ---------
             2         101 Match    Mismatch Match   
             1         101 Match    Mismatch Match  

Maybe you could consider creating a PLSQL procedure or function to do the checking of missmatched data ...
... something like below ...
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    Cursor t IS 
       Select Distinct DEAL_NUMBER From RBC_SWIFT_PARSER;
    Cursor c IS
        Select    COLUMN_NAME
        From      all_tab_columns 
        Where     OWNER = 'TABLE_OWNER_NAME' And TABLE_NAME = 'RBC_SWIFT_PARSER' And COLUMN_ID > 2;
    v_col       VarChar2(32);
    v_deal_num  Number(6) := 101; 
    v_sql       VarChar2(4000);
    v_result    VarChar2(4000) := 'Missmatched: ';
Begin
    Open t;
        Loop
            Fetch t Into v_deal_num;
            Exit When t%NOTFOUND;
            Open c;
                LOOP
                    Fetch c Into v_col;
                    Exit When c%NOTFOUND;
                    v_sql := 'Select Distinct CASE WHEN a.' || v_col || ' != ' || 'b.' || v_col || ' ' || 
                                       'THEN ' || '''' || v_col || '''' || ' ' || 
                                  'ELSE  ''OK'' END as col_name ' || 
                           'From RBC_SWIFT_PARSER a ' ||
                           'Inner Join RBC_SWIFT_PARSER b ON(a.DEAL_NUMBER = b.DEAL_NUMBER And b.HOST_REFERENCE != a.HOST_REFERENCE) ' || 
                           'Where a.DEAL_NUMBER = ' || v_deal_num;
                  Execute Immediate v_sql Into v_col;
                  If v_col != 'OK' Then 
                      v_result := v_result || Chr(10) || Chr(9) || v_col || ' For Deal ' || v_deal_num;
                  End If;                  
                END LOOP;
            Close c;
        End Loop;
    Close t;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_result); 
End;
/

--      R e s u l t : 
Missmatched: 
    COLUMN2 For Deal 101
    COLUMN1 For Deal 222

